# Detect support for srcdoc in iFrames

Tags: iframe, sandbox

Does anyone know how to detect if the srcdoc attribute of iFrame is supported by the browser without relaying on version checks, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick in JavaScript executed in a browser:

```
!!("srcdoc" in document.createElement("iframe"))
```

Source https://github.com/jugglinmike/srcdoc-polyfill/blob/master/srcdoc-polyfill.js#L19